# Sending large data over COM interface

Tags: c#, hash, interface, com

This is the first time I am implementing C# COM Interface with Perl. I would appreciate if somebody could help me to understand how a data of key value pairs be passed over the COM interface:

Is it possible to pass Hash?

or alternatively an array or array.

Another related doubt, Is it possible to pass object over COM interface?

If so, what about array of objects?

Answer (score 1):

Hashes aren't supported over COM, but [SAFEARRAY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221145%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)s are.  Safearrays can be nested, so you could pass an array of 2-element arrays.

While Objects per se can't be passed across COM, interfaces can be.  (COM is language neutral; passing a C++ object to a C# or Perl runtime isn't going to work.  COM interfaces have a common implementation across languages, and so can be passed around.)   Safearrays support arrays of interfaces, as well.